# proving sigma = BigTheta (BigΘ)

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity, theta-functions

I'm trying to solve a BigΘ problem, and could use a little guidance to make sure I'm on the right path.

So my question is to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{15} = Θ(n^{16})$

I know that for something to be BigΘ it needs to be BigO and BigΩ, these are my definitions for each:

BigO Definition: $(∃K,C>0)(∀n>K)f(n)<=C∗g(n)$

BigΩ Definition: $(∃K,C>0)(∀n>K)f(n)>=C∗g(n)$

- Step 1) solve for BigO

So I need to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{15} <= C* (n^{16})$ for all n > K

I choose K = 1, C = 1

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{15} <= (1) * (n^{16})$ for all n > 1

I choose n = 2

$\sum_{i=1}^{2} i^{15} <= (2^{16})$

$ 32769 <= 65536 $ which is true, and will be true for all n >1, thus BigO is proven.

- Step 2) solve for BigΩ                       [ where I mess up ]

So I need to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{15} >= C* (n^{16})$ for all n > K

I choose K = 1, C = 1

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{15} >= (1) * (n^{16})$ for all n > 1, which will always be false, ok.. so need to make RHS smaller.

I choose K = 1, C = .1    [ is this allowed? to choose a decimal point for C? My only restriction is that C  > 0.

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{15} >= (.1) * (n^{16})$ for all n > 1

I choose n = 2

$\sum_{i=1}^{2} i^{15} >= (.1) * (2^{16})$

$ 32769 <= (.1) 65536 $

$ 32769 <= 6553.6 $  which is true, and will always be true.